# VBA Error in Workbook_SheetChange: 458, Automation Type Not Supported

Tags: excel, vba

Edit: I'm almost convinced this is a carry-over from a bug for Excel for Mac documented [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-variable-uses-an-automation-type-not-supported-error-in-visual-basic-editor-in-excel-for-mac-c3125bf3-c30b-4d62-be42-d2f1bec0e5ad)

The error message originally showed up when clicking the Dropdown Menu in the worksheet's VBA Editor code window as documented in the link above. Since then, not only did the error below begin happening, but other attempts to edit a Range on the specific Worksheet produced the same error message. Even something simple like

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = 3.14159
```

What I did to resolve the issue:

1. Created a new worksheet
2. Copied contents of Sheet2 to the new worksheet
3. Copied the VBA snippet to the ThisWorkbook window instead of the new sheet's window.
4. And it worked - no 458 error message

Thank you QHarr for the feedback and fixes; I incorporated your suggestions into the code as well.

Original question below

I'm on a Mac, writing a Workbook Sheet Change event. It triggers correctly, but errors out on the line "Dim reservationRange As Range". Using Excel 16.19 Here is the error:

Run-time error '458':

Variable uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim reservationRange As Range
        reservationRange = .Range("I16:N500")
            ' If change was made in Reservations section
            If Not Intersect(Target, reservationRange) Is Nothing Then
                Dim reservationRow As Integer
                reservationRow = Target.Row
                ' If weekly budget is less than 0
                If .Range("O" & reservationRow).Value < 0 Then
                    ' Output Message and undo
                    MsgBox ("Error")
                    Application.Undo
                End If
            End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things I do note:

1. You need the `Set` keyword when assigning a Range object

   Set reservationRange = .Range("I16:N500")
2. `reservationRow` should be declared as `Long` to avoid potential overflow as row count in sheet can be greater than `Integer` can I hold (I believe true also for Mac but let me know)
3. You don't need `()` around `MsgBox ("Error")`
4. What happens if `Target` is more than one row? You will only get the first cell in the range's row.